# Why does clearing the arraylist for a RecyclerAdapter cause the adapter to update?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a button which clears the Arraylist that a RecyclerAdapter is using, but this causes the List to update even though I don't call `.notifyDataSetChanged()`

```
 @OnClick(R.id.btn_search)
    void onBtnSearchClick() {
        String name = String.valueOf(searchView.getQuery()).trim();
        if(name.equals("")){
            return;
        }

        btnSearch.setClickable(false);
        tvNoResults.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        
        centerProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        listUsers.clear();    //An ArrayList

        Log.d(TAG, "onBtnSearchClick: " + listUsers.size());
        
    }
```

Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to `RecyclerView` at all . Its all about the Object reference .
Consider the code block below

```
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding.recylerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(list));    
}
```

In this case if i use same `ArrayList` for showing data in `MyAdapter` i.e `list` . then it will be holding the same reference . and if any point of time i make any modification on `list` this will reflect in `MyAdapters's` list too because they Are pointing to same reference regardless of calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` .

this is why you have notify the adapter for any changes you made otherwise you will see weird behavior  when you access the data item for any position and some times exception too like `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the expected behavior?

Yes, If you're passing an `ArrayList` to your `Adapter`, and you're adding elements in `onCreate`, that would be before the app has drawn your first frame.

There is a moment where you're able to add elements because the adapter hasn't laid out the items.

And within your `onClick`, that would be after `onCreate` has finished, which means the `adapter` is already laid out.

Because of this reason, it might be refreshing without `.notifyDataSetChanged()`